# C++ STL container set&multiset:the insert operation with different return types

Tags: c++, stl, set, containers

About the STL container **set** and **multiset**,the return types of the **insert** functions are not all the same. 
**set** provides the following interface:

```
pair<iterator,bool> insert(const value_type& elem); 
iterator  insert(iterator pos_hint, const value_type& elem);
```

**multiset** provides the following interface:

```
iterator  insert(const value_type& elem); 
iterator  insert(iterator pos_hint, const value_type& elem);
```

In the first function of **set**, the member **second** of the **pair** structure returns whether the insertion is successful.The insertion of an element might fail for a set if it already contains an element with the same value.But in the second function of **set**,the insert function just returns an iterator.What will happen if the insertion fails?Could someone tell me that?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in the second function of set,the insert function just returns an iterator.What will happen if the insertion fails?

In the `set::insert` version that just returns a plain `iterator` (and not a `pair<iterator,bool>`), when an existing element is found the set is left unchanged and the `insert` will return an iterator to the existing element (that prevented the insertion).

In `multiset::insert`, the function is always successful.

#### 23.2.4 Associative Container Requirements

#### `iterator a.insert(p, t)`

> *Effects*: Inserts t if and only if there is no element with key
>   equivalent to the key of t in containers with unique keys; always
>   inserts t in containers with equivalent keys. always returns the
>   iterator pointing to the element with key equivalent to the key of t.
>   t is inserted as close as possible to the position just prior to p.